# Without using loop how can i iterate code instruction

Tags: c++, iteration, restart

When the user enters the wrong password the code is to restart when they have tried two times the code stops, but in my code when the user inputs the wrong information and it passes the password_attempts it continues to go everything else seems to be working just fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string myusername;
    string mypassword;
    bool Access_granted;
    int password_attempts;
    cout << "Enter your username: ";
    cin >> myusername;
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    cin >> mypassword;
    if (myusername == "veasy62" && mypassword == "a65908") {
        Access_granted = true;
        cout << "Access granted veasy62\n";
    }
    else if (myusername == "tveasy62" || mypassword == "a1065908") {
        Access_granted = true;
        cout << "Access granted tveasy62\n";
    }
    else {
        Access_granted = false;
        cout << password_attempts;
        cout << "Access Denied, Sorry try again\n";
        if (Access_granted == false) {
            if (password_attempts = 2) {
                password_attempts = password_attempts + 1;
                return main();
            }
            else {
                cout << "Sorry you have ran out of attempts\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot call main like a normal function. §3.6.1

Comment: Why can't you use loops? Are your f and w keys broken?

Comment: All else aside, it would probably help if you used `password_attempts == 2` instead of `password_attemps = 2`.

Comment: FYI, compilers with basic warnings turned on can warn about `if (password_attempts = 2)` and using `password_attempts` without initializing it. In addition, your `else` branch sets `Access_granted` to `false` and then checks if `Access_granted == false` without any intervening modification.

Comment: I also find it weird that you assign `Access_granted` but don't use it, or that you assign it to false then immediately check if it's false... don't confuse `=` and `==`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, No problem, `goto` doesn't use those keys ;) (Note to OP: `goto` is rarely appropriate, and certainly not here.)

Comment: If you can't use loops, then recursion is usually the wrong solution (especially with `main()`, since it is illegal in C++ to call it recursively at all).  Since you seem to only allow two password attempts, simply replicate the code for the check twice.

Comment: I don't understand this limitation of not using loops and see no utility in this at all doing things this way.  Is your program larger than this?  If so, what about the other parts of your program?  Are you allowed to use loops in those parts of your program?

Answer (score 2):

Your code got Litttle buggy.
Instead of && you used ||
also insteas of ==2 you assigned =2 to password_attempts in if condition 
Unnecessary if(false checking condition)
I removed all those and here is the code for task you want to achieve

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string myusername;
    string mypassword;
    bool Access_granted;
    int password_attempts=0;

    HERE : cout << "Enter your username: ";
    cin >> myusername;
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    cin >> mypassword;
    if (myusername == "veasy62" && mypassword == "a65908") {
        Access_granted = true;
        cout << "Access granted veasy62\n";
        break;
    }
    else if (myusername == "tveasy62" && mypassword == "a1065908") {
        Access_granted = true;
        cout << "Access granted tveasy62\n";
        break;
      }
    else {
        password_attempts = password_attempts + 1;
        Access_granted = false;
        cout << password_attempts;
        cout << "Access Denied, Sorry try again\n";

            if (password_attempts == 2) {
               cout << "Sorry you have ran out of attempts\n";
               return 0;

              //to exit main().can also use exit(0) using additional libraries
           }
          else{
           goto HERE;
        }
        }

 }
```

Comment: OP said he isn't allowed to use any loops.

Comment: Ohk changing my code ..now? @Michael Albers

Answer (score 1):

Instead of return you can use goto if you don't want to use loop.You can use "endl" instead of "\n".You can try this--

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string myusername;
   string mypassword;
   bool Access_granted;
   int password_attempts=0;
   restart:
   cout << "Enter your username: ";
   cin >> myusername;
   cout << "Enter your password: ";
   cin >> mypassword;
   if(myusername == "veasy62" && mypassword == "12")
   {
       Access_granted = true;
       cout<<"Access granted veasy62" << endl;
   }
   else if (myusername == "tveasy62" || mypassword == "a1065908" )
   {
      Access_granted = true;
      cout<<"Access granted tveasy62" << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      Access_granted = false; 


       if(Access_granted == false)
      {
          if(password_attempts < 2 )
          {
              cout << "Access Denied, Sorry try again" << endl;
              password_attempts = password_attempts + 1;
              cout << "you have remaining " << 2-password_attempts << " time   chances after this attempt" << endl;
              goto restart; 
          }
          else
          {
              cout << "Sorry you have ran out of attempts\n";
          }
      }
  }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, please don't use `goto`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what is the problem using "goto"? please explain

Comment: [Spaghetti coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).  You want to encourage this?

Comment: Oh, come on, get off this goto-is-evil never-use frenzy train. Every feature has it's use if used correctly and there isn't a problem with the way it is used in this answer.

Comment: @DeiDei Goto statements, if used, should be pointing *downwards* to a label, for example to escape from a deep loop nesting, not *upwards* as this example is doing.  If you're going to use `goto`, at least use it in the least worse way.  As soon as your `goto` makes you have your eyes look up or to scroll up to get to the target label, it is bad.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can actually get behind that. The only time I've used `goto` is to get out of a nested loop where a single `break` doesn't do it. But to say "never use it" just sounds too pretentious.

Answer (score 1):

So you say you can't use loops.  Well here is a solution that uses a recursive template.  There are no "gotos", and is easily adjustable by changing the template parameter to a larger number.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <int attempts>
struct password_entry
{
    static bool get_entry(std::string& myusername, std::string& mypassword)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter your username: ";
        std::cin >> myusername;
        std::cout << "Enter your password: ";
        std::cin >> mypassword;
        if (myusername == "veasy62" && mypassword == "12")
        {
            std::cout << "Access granted veasy62" << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
        if ( attempts > 1 )
            std::cout << "Access denied.  You have " << attempts - 1 << " attempts remaining\n";
        return password_entry<attempts - 1>::get_entry(myusername, mypassword);
    }
};

template <> 
struct password_entry<0>
{
    static bool get_entry(const std::string&, const std::string&)
    {
        std::cout << "Sorry you have ran out of attempts\n";
        return false;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::string mypass, myuser;

    // max 2 attempts 
    bool access_granted = password_entry<2>::get_entry(myuser, mypass);
    if ( access_granted )
       std::cout << "Welcome current user";
    else
       std::cout << "Please call 555-5555 to reset your password";
}
```

To adjust the number of attempts, the password_entry template parameter call just needs to change.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/hQFLGS)

Edit:  Adjusted code to not use constructor.

Comment: Supposing _password entry_ waits for user inputs in a real scenario, is your suggestions to do that in a constructor? I think it's not a good idea.

Comment: Supposing we could use loops, like any real program would use?  You get what you pay for -- no loops, less functionality.

Comment: I adjusted the code to use a static function rather than the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

so what I understand from you question you want let user enter his password two times and if both were wrong finish the program right?
then you can write like this.

Edited :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string myusername;
    string mypassword;
    bool Access_granted;
    int password_attempts=0;




        cout << "Enter your username: ";
        cin >> myusername;
        cout << "Enter your password: ";
        cin >> mypassword;
        if (myusername == "veasy62" && mypassword == "a65908") {
            Access_granted = true;
            cout << "Access granted veasy62\n";
        }
        else if (myusername == "tveasy62" || mypassword == "a1065908") {
            Access_granted = true;
            cout << "Access granted tveasy62\n";
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            Access_granted = false;
            cout << "Access Denied, Sorry try again\n";
            cout << "Enter your username: ";
            cin >> myusername;
            cout << "Enter your password: ";
            cin >> mypassword;
            if (myusername == "veasy62" && mypassword == "a65908") {
                Access_granted = true;
                cout << "Access granted veasy62\n";
            }
            else if (myusername == "tveasy62" || mypassword == "a1065908") {
                Access_granted = true;
                cout << "Access granted tveasy62\n";
                system("pause");
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {


                    cout << "Sorry you have ran out of attempts\n";
                    cout << "Access Denied";
                    system("pause");
                    return -1;
                }
            }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP said he isn't allowed to use any loops

Comment: No loops allowed !

Comment: I just edit it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string myusername;
    string mypassword;
    bool Access_granted;
    int password_attempts=0;
    cout << "Enter your username: ";
    cin >> myusername;
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    cin >> mypassword;
    if (myusername == "veasy62" && mypassword == "a65908") {
        Access_granted = true;
        cout << "Access granted veasy62\n";
    }
    else if (myusername == "tveasy62" || mypassword == "a1065908") {
        Access_granted = true;
        cout << "Access granted tveasy62\n";
    }
    else {
        Access_granted = false;
        cout << password_attempts;
        cout << "Access Denied, Sorry try again\n";
        if (Access_granted == false) {
            if (password_attempts <=2) {
                password_attempts = password_attempts + 1;
                return main();
            }
            else {
                cout << "Sorry you have ran out of attempts\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot call `main` from a C++ program.  This was already stated in the main comments above by @CaptainGriraffe with citation from the C++ standard document.

Answer (score 0):

Use goto 
Or if you like modules try a recursive function.it will work like you are trying to do.

```
public int accessAllowed(int notrys=0)
{
if(notrys<2)
return 0;

string username,password;

//take username password

If(//condition 1)
return 1;

else if(//condition 2)
return 1;

else
return accessAllowed(notrys+1);
}
```

though goto will be efficient.

Also there are lots of bugs in your code

1. Nooftrys not initialised(I think you needed 0 as inititial value)
2. || in place of &&
3. =2 while checking for trys overflow,use <2 for 2 tries.